# Find time of execution after executing using N threads

Tags: python, multithreading, execution-time

I am trying to find the difference in time of execution as I keep increasing the number of threads. Basically, I want to find how long the outer loop takes to execute after completing the jobs in all the threads in that loop.

```
import threading
import time
from math import sqrt


def run(start, end):
    [sqrt(i) for i in range(start,end)]

n_threads = 2
n_vals = 1000000
start_time = time.time()
for n_threads in range(1,11):
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(0,n_threads):
        first = int((n_vals/n_threads)*i)
        last = int((n_vals/n_threads)*(i+1))
        t=threading.Thread(target=run, args=(first,last))
        t.start()
    print("For Threads = "+ str(n_threads) +" --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This is a simple program to split the job equally between threads where n_threads is the number of threads.I want to find the execution time when n_threads = 1,2....10. However, in my present code, I don't think I'm getting the time after all the threads have executed, but rather the time is given in parallel while the rest of the threads are executing. How do I fix this?

Comment: One problem with what you are trying to do is Python has a global interpreter lock (GIL). What that basically means is your program is actually only interleaving the threads, not doing true concurrency. You will not experience any speedup. You can trying using the multiprocessing library instead if you want.

Comment: Is there still a way to find the time at which a set of threads in an iteration finished execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you are not getting the time it takes for all threads to finish. You need to append each thread to a list. Then call the join method to wait for that thread to finish its work. Also, note the comment by Strikeskid.

```
start_time = time.time()
threads = []
for i in range(0,n_threads):
    t=threading.Thread(target=run, args=(first,last))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print("For Threads = "+ str(n_threads) +" --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```